# Serverless Deploy on Windows

Tags: python, windows, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have been facing  a trouble to do Serverless deploy on my dev machine. This is the error that I've got:

[image]

This is my serverless yml file configuration:

```
service: serverless-flask

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-wsgi

custom:
  wsgi:
    app: myapp.views:app
    packRequirements: false
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: true

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  stage: dev
  region: ap-southeast-1

functions:
  app:
    handler: wsgi.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'
```

Any idea which configuration that should I used to running serverless deploy command with python flask application ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure if you can use pip for a AWS serverless deployment. I have some apps serverless and I have to put in root folder my dependencies.

You have to run :

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=$PREFIX_PATH" package_name
```

So, when you have this in your root you don't need to run pip.

Also, you can find other steps in AWS Docs:
[AWS Deployment Lambdas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html)

Obviously, this is a Lambda documentation but in short words serverless creates lambda functions with a API Gateway Endpoints, through a CloudFormation settings.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You can absolutely use pip to install dependencies in AWS using the Serverless Framework. I am doing that in an application I am developing.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a few things.

1. Use Python 3.7 instead of 3.6. Lambda now supports that environment.
2. Upgrade your pip setup tools with `pip install --upgrade setuptools`
3. Install the C++ build tools from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

If none of that works, enable the SLS_DEBUG=*. In Powershell you do that with `$env:SLS_DEBUG="*"`. And run your deployment again to see a more descriptive error.